# Python requests downloading from url not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to download a xls file from a url using python requests library

The url is
https://dart.fss.or.kr/pdf/download/excel.do?rcp_no=20200330003962&dcm_no=7203189&lang=ko

I have no issues on downloading the file with my browser, but my code does not work.

```
import requests
url = 'https://dart.fss.or.kr/pdf/download/excel.do?rcp_no=20200330003962&dcm_no=7203189&lang=ko'
response = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, stream=True)

with open('test8.xls', 'wb') as r: 
    r.write(response.content)
```

I have tried with and without allow_redirects, stream parameters, but they all do not work.
I have even tried attempts with other combinations of request headers(cookies, referer, host etc.) but they all do not work.

Can anyone give me a solution?

The above url is from http://dart.fss.or.kr/pdf/download/main.do?rcp_no=20200330003962&dcm_no=7203189

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what does not work? Do you get an error? Something else?

Comment: The file is 0bytes. I cannot get any content.

Comment: Any luck with my solution?

Comment: thank you very much. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to use a user agent. The below works for me:

```
import requests
url = 'https://dart.fss.or.kr/pdf/download/excel.do?rcp_no=20200330003962&dcm_no=7203189&lang=ko'
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=user_agent)

with open('test8.xls', 'wb') as r: 
    r.write(response.content)
```